# Untrack Files From Git LFS To Allow Me To Push to GitHub Server

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I have a couple text files (which all happen to be CMakeLists files) that are being tracked by Git LFS and I don't know how to remove them from being tracked. I know I am only tracking ".a" files and when I try to uninstall Git LFS and reinstall it, the text files still appear in the tracked files list. I've tried pushing to the GitHub server but it gives me this error:

```
Git LFS: (0 of 57 files, 11 skipped) 0 B / 69.49 KB, 522.26 MB skipped         
Unable to find object (8ceb4b9ee5adedde47b31e975c1d90c73ad27b6b165a1dcd80c7c545eb65b903) locally.
Unable to find object (9ccf26cfe845e0eb8bb58053e47366e7ab6b697ae010f7650978d4b71b7d1fc1) locally.
Unable to find object (c7db155f60ba22bd15a44eaeb2a9e0f1d30f19892d3bbf338dfa3dbf80403fd8) locally.
Unable to find object (b04a94bb8a6e50edf9874377751fbaa63139ede6dd6305cd06aad3b5d5a1d340) locally.
Unable to find object (95cd3e2ade6564783d4f2bdee3a13c9855be1ce8674da896424be31a0f91729c) locally.
Unable to find object (b2b87815faaffffdc2336e41c21954e88a177a59b5140a4bd23af84e3f78817f) locally.
Unable to find object (7c92b8482fd7790efa30b21603387ed82cc8244f2e784397902a68026f5804f1) locally.
Unable to find object (057606c0398f1a5e5d55956afc31b058dd2ce8ff983bc3b678e39170d9f91a78) locally.
Unable to find object (a6e6823b47af8518f9fb800041ce1c33da4403d8cf5de9e3d4dc20d49c1de320) locally.
Unable to find object (607023b1043b79aac53c386b47bffc010eb0c7cb2b8b17664a549d3ac86cde43) locally.
Unable to find object (74db2d8bdcc8a22afb73fff5854cf3871a1758673d823c4cc9d5d84b5a785524) locally.
Unable to find object (d385c297093d780b7c687ada3c9990f702aa91c54b8433ca01fb83f03864fb35) locally.
Unable to find object (430bbc8c5e3ffbcb0ea05e7d7b8ebe3af7f71832dff0a36a6b68737b87107676) locally.
Unable to find object (2c463a5095ac6472752fd8de4c4af111ada4d2f0ada526bc198d6d1e7a6c98fa) locally.
Unable to find object (8b05c16851a401e9be0bfc9223385d587f3553fd7e7e5b4f7dedb2f21ea07c24) locally.
Unable to find object (666627350b016a5d828dda3b5d916f34366eca94948552f140e49c8e4d33a37b) locally.
Git LFS: (0 of 57 files, 11 skipped) 0 B / 69.49 KB, 522.26 MB skippe
Unable to find object (b012417ab00d06768dc6be6734a8a38226d8a5cc7035d94e24b56674cc22e927) locally.
Unable to find object (aa698f6dd6d7f1d6c03d4413eaf2acf789003a18f20990f96888a2246d553734) locally.
Unable to find object (19e6166aa63c1c0fc4af8999d80b3db1e2ffbde32ed78a6c6d83276a474d05ee) locally.
Unable to find object (ae52d87dbdfbd9396cfb2fd351a9c36c6fe060b6731dbc22aed837e0a0d460ec) locally.
Unable to find object (929c65ffe6f710fb79c06bf40d080baf7d66ef2487a47429f79505b003031e22) locally.
Unable to find object (4358275f55f4a8e0f1a74ac1d0f1e413e1772fb29b9bb40868cdd3448451e880) locally.
Unable to find object (592b8b5770f960ccaf22807f4c2d66041b3e2a9c53a7c8c74bfcd544854f1bb7) locally.
Unable to find object (b6f0eebf50d22d05666dccf8ae4d8712a1be67d0fb16ba8f99ad7f59a0295f8e) locally.
Unable to find object (e2f4b59f3b9b592bc3428b71c628ea8180e12b70f33ca0dfb260bddce476efb4) locally.
Unable to find object (b17c96be265826256d5b28b03059eaa005d3d6ebee4ec1ef3e3df58ef6f9ae27) locally.
Unable to find object (092799c2693794ba318e683c68c79c76f445eaaf39996fd269ad86402e236641) locally.
Unable to find object (ecb71a0e12ff6a0aaa4130d7ba0d666fea664e64310aa1f64ecb96a458e2b42b) locally.
Unable to find object (7923cfae9b44cebe64fb3ec9da736785ff5fc50de97e4bd4f1cf801033d067f5) locally.
Unable to find object (3b52e169ef93ca4cc8e63d4995dab47ee39f7bbe864c468c17c652035dafdebe) locally.
Unable to find object (dfb0f2fdc1fe4985d221748846b2aafa4338dc4a13b6e0c60ed18bb7cf930a66) locally.
Unable to find object (5f7e9d3dc61745a9866fdb4bea3a0b071eed6e3b28a844f5f6ae009ff91e8764) locally.
Unable to find object (f538681c9973a0cf4aee4af8000bcc49df36469dc3ed4f71286c990d60b830aa) locally.
Unable to find object (dc9abcf4442efa396771f50d1c27e94d8db3f17309e1f53b63ea8b341ec52c83) locally.
Unable to find object (a3b9a7bdc7e80032dff6ade2607ca606924d4bf776a6039424e9e41821d5b614) locally.
Unable to find object (e45d38111e54e01fc8dd72e363a20b443df4203e5d6bb0f8bee3bd9be561fe4d) locally.
Unable to find object (3ce52d66e3753088e35d259bbbd72ffcf943690d960bba8bea037520e4636162) locally.
Unable to find object (aaffd843ca479e81b3be852520991201728ec91f7e00db6bf85939ab563456d7) locally.
Unable to find object (4d73adcecd840f04907c247fd139b17c3e414a9a77c5317933fa32f5d056bb84) locally.
Unable to find object (a0edd4738e9517a1bf15bfedba9500492b2be6539325ff53ab08119e539e20d4) locally.
Unable to find object (0c245574796daec63408f10d43e4db1c40789dffaa01b350b7daafeee3a99169) locally.
Unable to find object (e8d45cd46e40bff15b06dcdc9007131844745a938e3b7fcf60cbdbeef73114d4) locally.
Unable to find object (2067753ca954689f81375d919b98615049f94411e9f9c817702e2fe1992ea212) locally.
Unable to find object (8f6366c65c3ab620577f269a334ef3e622015306a094d34a5b447028b2b58d55) locally.
Unable to find object (296f16383a95d97fdca76ef137943ee46740646502aaa4e0a86405467bc7948a) locally.
Unable to find object (7bcc0dc0a1c5b90dc19886071782de2222e2ed039d76ccba7787ed0b30984ebc) locally.
Unable to find object (9c08213b3514c3e3e6407e6cc17bfd7813c335ef6c25f02dd92399162560dc04) locally.
Unable to find object (e3d4f157b62ad0ef33ca5e5148d26e4cb12377f972d301c5d8bf0783ccd0e887) locally.
Unable to find object (12d1faa5d66e9696b5ddb7488920926eadf60d470b2c143ad3f0b12fe16027e3) locally.
Unable to find object (8279a05913222d45fd32fd8d29b772684746dc4ee7f1549ba19efc273dc87cd2) locally.
Unable to find object (73e7ee97b8d8e0697906ed70456cc94bfdf73cceb8f8344afc82759ebbb7ef9d) locally.
Unable to find object (292757f296dfbb9d390e0e4a9fc8c74bc65834a0507afd3a0791a876ca72540f) locally.
Unable to find object (3217f8a3bd8979e08ff1d9217f8f9e6364f5b248228247f1b805167ee1ea8787) locally.
Unable to find object (0e7dd222de4e6a330b98289de8c8bc62c448856d7e70df4787490eac1a8d9afc) locally.
Unable to find object (3a433e47e159feb23a69f00b528e707ce00e2149be80959daa05164a343b0e2e) locally.
Unable to find object (ca8e21988fde2e95f968c617d7a007d770c2e6b01bd732d8c6d741288644283e) locally.
```

This is what I get when I try doing `git lfs ls-files`:

```
2c463a5095 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/CMakeLists.txt
b012417ab0 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/CMakeLists.txt
9c08213b35 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/Cholesky/CMakeLists.txt
092799c269 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/CholmodSupport/CMakeLists.txt
aa698f6dd6 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/Core/CMakeLists.txt
592b8b5770 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/Core/arch/AltiVec/CMakeLists.txt
3a433e47e1 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/Core/arch/CMakeLists.txt
4358275f55 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/Core/arch/Default/CMakeLists.txt
5f7e9d3dc6 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/Core/arch/NEON/CMakeLists.txt
e45d38111e - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/CMakeLists.txt
3ce52d66e3 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/Core/products/CMakeLists.txt
8f6366c65c - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/Core/util/CMakeLists.txt
ae52d87dbd - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/Eigen2Support/CMakeLists.txt
929c65ffe6 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/Eigen2Support/Geometry/CMakeLists.txt
4d73adcecd - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/Eigenvalues/CMakeLists.txt
b6f0eebf50 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/Geometry/CMakeLists.txt
f538681c99 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/Geometry/arch/CMakeLists.txt
a0edd4738e - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/Householder/CMakeLists.txt
19e6166aa6 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/IterativeLinearSolvers/CMakeLists.txt
8279a05913 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/Jacobi/CMakeLists.txt
0c24557479 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/LU/CMakeLists.txt
e3d4f157b6 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/LU/arch/CMakeLists.txt
a3b9a7bdc7 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/MetisSupport/CMakeLists.txt
e2f4b59f3b - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/OrderingMethods/CMakeLists.txt
dfb0f2fdc1 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/PaStiXSupport/CMakeLists.txt
b17c96be26 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/PardisoSupport/CMakeLists.txt
3217f8a3bd - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/QR/CMakeLists.txt
aaffd843ca - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/SPQRSupport/CMakeLists.txt
292757f296 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/SVD/CMakeLists.txt
3b52e169ef - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/SparseCholesky/CMakeLists.txt
e8d45cd46e - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/SparseCore/CMakeLists.txt
7bcc0dc0a1 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/SparseLU/CMakeLists.txt
296f16383a - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/SparseQR/CMakeLists.txt
2067753ca9 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/StlSupport/CMakeLists.txt
7923cfae9b - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/SuperLUSupport/CMakeLists.txt
ecb71a0e12 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/UmfPackSupport/CMakeLists.txt
73e7ee97b8 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/misc/CMakeLists.txt
12d1faa5d6 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/src/plugins/CMakeLists.txt
74db2d8bdc - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ORB_SLAM/Thirdparty/DBoW2/CMakeLists.txt
95cd3e2ade - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ORB_SLAM/Thirdparty/DBoW2/DBoW2/LICENSE.txt
057606c039 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ORB_SLAM/Thirdparty/DBoW2/DUtils/LICENSE.txt
b04a94bb8a - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ORB_SLAM/Thirdparty/DBoW2/LICENSE.txt
c7db155f60 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ORB_SLAM/Thirdparty/g2o/CMakeLists.txt
0e7dd222de - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ORB_SLAM/Thirdparty/g2o/Changes.txt
7c92b8482f - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ORB_SLAM/Thirdparty/g2o/doc/license-bsd.txt
8ceb4b9ee5 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ORB_SLAM/Thirdparty/g2o/doc/license-gpl.txt
9ccf26cfe8 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ORB_SLAM/Thirdparty/g2o/doc/license-lgpl.txt
dc9abcf444 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ORB_SLAM/Thirdparty/g2o/g2o/CMakeLists.txt
b2b87815fa - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ORB_SLAM/Thirdparty/g2o/g2o/core/CMakeLists.txt
b4036ac921 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ORB_SLAM/Thirdparty/g2o/g2o/solvers/CMakeLists.txt
d385c29709 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ORB_SLAM/Thirdparty/g2o/g2o/solvers/cholmod/CMakeLists.txt
666627350b - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ORB_SLAM/Thirdparty/g2o/g2o/solvers/dense/CMakeLists.txt
a6e6823b47 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ORB_SLAM/Thirdparty/g2o/g2o/stuff/CMakeLists.txt
ca8e21988f - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ORB_SLAM/Thirdparty/g2o/g2o/types/CMakeLists.txt
430bbc8c5e - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ORB_SLAM/Thirdparty/g2o/g2o/types/sba/CMakeLists.txt
8b05c16851 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ORB_SLAM/Thirdparty/g2o/g2o/types/sim3/CMakeLists.txt
607023b104 - Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ORB_SLAM/Thirdparty/g2o/g2o/types/slam3d/CMakeLists.txt
12873d8e42 * Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/cholmod/libs/libAMD.a
b7d366e2e9 * Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/cholmod/libs/libCAMD.a
3f187a18fb * Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/cholmod/libs/libCCOLAMD.a
d0c4ef5802 * Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/cholmod/libs/libCOLAMD.a
ccdfa3f749 * Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/cholmod/libs/libcholmod.a
3e2bd9f480 * Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/libg2o.a
9bdbeb2116 * Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/libjpeg.a
a89d7f7dd8 * Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/ofxiOSBoost/libs/boost/ios/boost.a
eed878716f * Virtual Director/Assets/NatCam/Core/Plugins/iOS/libNatCamCore.a
88f0358ded * Virtual Director/Assets/NatCam/Extended/Plugins/iOS/libNatCamExtended.a
3bfbfc553b * Virtual Director/Assets/NatCam/Professional/Plugins/iOS/libNatCamProfessional.a
```

I want to know how to remove the text files from being tracked and allow me to push to my GitHub server.

Comment: Tracking is controlled using `.gitattributes` files.  Marcelo Avila de Oliveira's advice should work *if* the tracking was done sensibly (i.e. in the `.gitattributes` file at the root of the repo), but unfortunately some tools - or some users who think they're being clever - create .gitattributes in subdirectories and set up lfs tracking there.  If you `cd` to the repo root and do a `find . -name .gitattributes` what do you see?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger The only `.gitattributes` file I get is in the root directory, which is just this. https://gist.github.com/PavanJakhu/f75d8b329751680f4a8a98c0e0e14fa2

Comment: @PavanJakhu hey! I am having exactly the same problem, did u managed to get it fixed? I am completely stuck. I created the .gitattributes at the beggining, it doesnt include *.prefab files, but for some weird reason similar to yours, I get that problem telling me that some *.prefab files are being tracked by LFS. 

Any help could be really valued

Answer (score 2):

To view the Git LFS paths tracked, execute:

```
git lfs track
```

To untrack *.txt files, execute:

```
git lfs untrack *.txt
```

Comment: This is what I get when I try to `git lfs track` `Listing tracked patterns
    *.a (.gitattributes)`
So it doesn't think I'm tracking *.txt files and it doesn't untrack them when I try the second command.

Comment: It seems that the *.txt files were tracked by git lfs in the past (when the all these *.txt files were created). Maybe someone removed the *.txt rule from .gitattributes but forgot to remove the *.txt files from LFS. Check the .gitattributes history with: git log -- .gitattributes

Comment: It doesn't seem like I was tracking *.txt files at all according to my git log. The only times I've touched that file is when I first committed it and then when I added the last 4 lines to it. Here is a link to it of what it currently is. https://gist.github.com/PavanJakhu/f75d8b329751680f4a8a98c0e0e14fa2

Comment: Let's think in another cenario: is it possible that someone else added the *.txt files to LFS but forget to commit the change in .gitattributes? After that he/she could have tried to remove the *.txt files from LFS but make something wrong (I don't know what)?

Comment: That would have been possible since I didn't start using this repository until recently but none of the commits that change the .gitattribute file except me. If that were to happen, how would I get rid of track *.txt files?

Comment: Is it feasible to remove the *.txt files from the repository using the "git rm"?

Comment: Okay, I tried doing that. I did the command `git rm -r *.txt` in my root directory then committed the changes while discarding changes that weren't those CMakeList files. This is the error I get when trying to push to the GitHub server: `open /Volumes/CLOUD & YAP BACKUP2/VirtualDirector/Plugins/iOS Third Party Dependencies/Eigen/CMakeLists.txt: no such file or directory
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/AWE-Company/VirtualDirector.git'`

Comment: Uhm... let try something in a different direction... have you tried to track the *.txt files using the "git lfs track" command to see if the problem is solved? Then you could try to remove them.

Comment: So I undid what I previously did with remove the txt files from the repository. I tried doing the command `git lfs track *.txt` then tried `git lfs untrack *.txt`. I `git lfs ls-files` but the output looks the exact same as I initially posted.

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for me was to `git lfs uninstall`, and then push to the remote repo (without reinstalling).

I imagine this will only be effective if you want to untrack all files tracked by Git LFS. Not untrack only some while leaving the others tracked.

I intended to untrack all tracked files, and that did the trick.